# how to set receiver for mobile data enabled disabled?

Tags: android

I want to set receiver for any type of mobile data enabled/disabled such as 3g etc.

I am using this code for on receive...

```
 ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {


               Toast.makeText(context, "Mobile data enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             }
```

and this coode in manifest

`<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverforWifiBluetoothData" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

but in some device it can't work properly and many case receiver trigger after some time and some time i will not trigger onReceive() of Broadcastreceiver ?

Please help me either I going through wrong code or it need some other trick to resolve?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Broadcast receiver for mobile data state change listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344547/set-broadcast-receiver-for-mobile-data-state-change-listener)